# CQRS, Should I have bidirectional aggregate reference?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

Suppose we have domain Character and Player. Character owned by Player.

```
Player
   PlayerID : GUID
   OwnedCharacterIDs : Guid[]

Character
   CharacterID : GUID
   OwnerPlayerID : GUID
```

While my business logic required both side of references.

Question is

Should I have both direction reference? This will cause redundant of truth have to manage consistency in both side.

Or should choose only one reference side. And use some repository(eventual consistency) to help reference to another one? like this

```
CharacterRefRepo
   GetCharacterIDsByOwner(Guid playerID) GUID[]

or maybe

PlayerRefRepo
   GetPlayerIDByCharacterID(Guid characterID) GUID
```

**Update:**

I found out that both ways are eventual consistency.

So only benefit to have bidirectional now is we don't have to build another helper repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with bidirectional references is you would have to keep them in sync at all times. This is hard given the rule that only one aggregate should change at a time.

Using the repo seems like the way to go.